# SharePoint 2010 Document Library 'Send To' Across Web Apps

Tags: document-library, web-application

I'm am trying to use the 'Send To' -> 'Other Location' on a document to send it to another 'Web App' in the same farm.

It is working on the same 'Web App' to another 'Site Collection'.

Both 'Web Apps' are in the 'Local Intranet' setting with IE Security Settings.

The issue I am getting is that the document is not coping. The Dialog Box stick on 'Current Action: Uploading Item'

1 'Web App' is for an internal 'Document Management System' (DMS) and the other 'Web App' is for publicly available documents. Not all documents in the DMS will need to be publicly available.

I wanted to use the 'Send To' method as when user changes a document that has been made publicly available from the DMS they are prompted to update the copy in the publicly available Web App

Comment: How are your permissions configured?

Comment: I have tried it using 2 'Site Collection Administrator' accounts (on both 'Web Apps'). Both accounts also have full control permission via the 'Owners' Group in 'Site Permissions'. I have tried it with and without 'Anonymous Access' turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it should be possible only for IE using ActiveX control on a machine with Office (accordingly to [http://office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/specify-a-send-to-destination-for-a-library-HA010120850.aspx)):

> If you copy files from a client computer that has a program that is compatible with Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, such as Microsoft Office Word 2007, and a browser that supports Microsoft ActiveX Controls, such as Microsoft Internet Explorer, you can use the Send To command to copy files not only between libraries within a site collection, but also between different Web applications. If you copy files from the browser of a client computer that does not support ActiveX Controls, you will be able to copy files only to libraries within site collections that share the same domain name (top-level site name) as the source library.

You can see ActiveX control on a copy screen [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/send-to-operation-between-sharepoint-and-onedrive-library/).